# AWS CLI powershell command failing with "Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 6 (char 5)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cli

Below is the powershell command I am trying to run:

```
aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn myListenerARN --default-actions ' [ { "Type": "forward", "Order": 1, "ForwardConfig" : { "TargetGroups": [ { "TargetGroupArn" : "TargetARN1", "Weight": 50 }, { "TargetGroupArn": "TargetARN2", "Weight": 50 } ] } } ] '
```

It returns this error: `Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 6 (char 5)`. Is there something wrong with the command?

Comment: it seems the problem is with your json structure. TRY this `[{"Type":"forward","Order":1,"ForwardConfig":{"TargetGroups":[{"TargetGroupArn":"TargetARN1","Weight":50},{"TargetGroupArn":"TargetARN2","Weight":50}]}}]` 
Also, mention the default type properly enclosed in double quotes `aws elbv2 modify-listener --listener-arn arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:listener/app/my-load-balancer/50dc6c495c0c9188/f2f7dc8efc522ab2 --default-actions Type=forward,TargetGroupArn=arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-west-2:123456789012:targetgroup/my-new-targets/2453ed029918f21f` like this

Comment: I removed the single quote around the json but then it throws errors related to formatting of the command.

Comment: I need to check and understand it then.. But instead of json, could you please try a small sample ? I am sure the issue is with your formatting of the code.